# Class 'Swift_Mime_Headers_UnstructuredHeader' not found in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am sending e-mails from Laravel app, the e-mail is working fine in localhost, but not working in production server.
Note: Hosted the application in Shared Hosting (as its for personal use)

**My Controller**

```
public function createapplication(Request $request)
{
    $leaves = Application::create([
        'emp_id'    => auth()->user()->id,
        'from_date' => request('from_date'),
        'to_date'   => request('to_date'),
        'days'      => request('days'),
        'reason'    => request('reason')
    ]);

    $fromdate = $request->from_date;
    $to_date  = $request->to_date;
    $days     = $request->days;
    $reason   = $request->reason;

    $data = array(
        'name'      => auth()->user()->name, 
        'From_date' => $fromdate, 
        'To_date'   => $to_date, 
        'Days'      => $days, 
        'Reason'    => $reason
    );

    Mail::send('mail.leavesmail', $data, function($message) use ($fromdate, $to_date, $days, $reason)
    {   
        $message->to('example.com', 'example')->subject('Leave Application');
        $message->from('example.com', "example");
        $message->cc(auth()->user()->email);
    });

    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Leave Application Submitted Successfully!');

}
```

Comment: Guessing you might need to install swiftmailer for laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For personal use or not, using your own host to send mail is generally a bad idea. There are many problems that you may come across from not being able to send mail (Host disables mail sending to stop spam). Mail going into spam (Mail comes from a known spam IP) among other issues. For this reason I would suggest [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/), it's free tier will keep you going forever.

Onto the problem itself, have you run `composer install` it looks as if a class is just missing due to that?

Comment: I checked the files , every thing looks fine, still the same error

Comment: @GURURUGI Have you run composer install? You may need to do some [extra steps](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e). It's also not recommended to have shared hosting for Laravel.

Comment: I can't run composer install on my production server, so i checked the swift dependencies in vendor folder, all files exists, still i cant't figure out the solution. Yes i know shared hosting is not recommended. I am just struck with this problem. Thanks for those extra steps, i wolud try and revert back.

Comment: Yeh I think the problem is that you can't run `composer install`, as when you run it also dumps the autoloader hence why the files are there but PHP can't see it. you need to copy over the autoload file that composer generates

Comment: Solved the problem by reuploading the swiftmailer folder inside vendor/swiftmailer/.. Thanks for the help